# Call by reference-stream and char in c++

Tags: c++

My latest homework assignment is to write a program that reads a textfile and outputs the number of lines, words and characters.

I'm just starting out, all I'm trying to do right now is to let the user type in the file name and then the file will open. This is my not-working code, I must be missing something obvious, I'm just trying to pass the stream and char to the 'input' function.

Any pointers?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

//Define functions.
void input(ifstream& fin, char& fileName);

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    char fileName[20];
    input(fin, fileName);
    return 0;
}

void input(ifstream& fin, char& fileName)
{
    cout << "Input file name: ";
    cin >> fileName;
    fin.open(fileName);

    if(fin.fail())
    {
        cout << "The file:  " << fileName << " does not open." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    //return;
}
```

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile. You should take a look at the compile errors, fix the problems they indicate. Or if you don't understand the errors you get you should post them and ask specific questions about the errors you don't understand.

Comment: Yeah, it does not compile, this is the first error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'char&' from a temporary of type 'char*'|

Answer (score 1):

This will probably get you closer. At least past your compilation errors, but you still need work on a few things. Get thee to a reference manual and a debugger.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

//Define functions.
void input(ifstream& fin, string& fileName);

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    string fileName;
    input(fin, fileName);
    return 0;
}

void input(ifstream& fin, string& fileName)
{
    cout << "Input file name: ";
    cin >> fileName;
    fin.open(fileName.c_str());

    if(fin.fail())
    {
        cout << "The file:  " << fileName << " does not open." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    //return;
}
```

Not the way I'd do this, but you gotta learn sometime. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody, I'll go on from here, although I'm curious how you would do this :) The assignment description said to use functions for all of this, so I was just going to write these functions: input, nrLines, nrWords, nrChars and output.

Comment: Just keep doing what you're doing, ask questions when you're truly stuck, etc. you could put this up to a thousand engineers on SO and get a thousand different answers. There is rarely a singular "right" way, but there are *correct* ways, and that should be your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax isn't correct. Use:

```
void input(ifstream *fin, char *fileName);
```

And:

```
input(&fin, &fileName); // call
```

Here you are passing the reference of the variable to the pointer (`*`).

Make the required changes and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `char&` is a reference to a single `char`, not an array or a string.

This will work much better if you use `std::string fileName`, and pass a `string&` parameter around.

Answer (score 0):

your `input` function's *second param*: `char& fileName` is a **reference to a char**; whereas - what you need is a **reference to an array of 20 chars**

Thus, change it to: `void input(ifstream& fin,`**`char (&fileName)[20])`**